LWC component to search Account records not displaying data
I'm new to LWC and trying to build a basic component to display account records based on the search term entered but it is not displaying the data even though data is retrieved from Apex.
Apex Code:
public with sharing class accountController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccounts(String searchTerm){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        String searchKeyword = '';
        if(searchTerm != null){
            searchKeyword = '%'+searchTerm+'%';
            accList = [SELECT Id,Name,Phone FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :searchKeyword];
        }
        return accList;
    }
}

HTML:
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-input label="Search Accounts" name="search-accounts" onchange={handleSearch}></lightning-input>
        <template if:true={dataPresent}>
            <div style="height: 300px">
                <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={accList}
                columns={columns}
                hide-checkbox-column="true">
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:false={dataPresent}>
            <p>No Accounts found.</p>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/accountController.getAccounts';

const columns = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'}
];

export default class AccountSearchCmp extends LightningElement {
    @track searchTerm;
    @track accList = [];
    @track dataPresent = false;
    @wire(getAccounts,{searchTerm: '$searchTerm'})
    wiredAccounts({error,data}){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else if(data){
            this.accList = data;
            console.log('Data: '+this.accList.length);
            if(this.accList.length>0){
                this.dataPresent = true; 
            }
        } else {
            this.dataPresent = false;
        }
    }

    handleSearch(event){
        this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
        //console.log(this.searchTerm);
    }
}


The template (HTML file) can access only instance variable: the variable must be defined inside the JS class. columns is defined outside the class, so it's a static variable, therefore the datatable receives undefined instead of the columns definition.
You could expose it using a getter property. I would suggest using a getter for dataPresent too.
Moreover you don't need @track, since property used in the template or in a wire adapter are already reactive. Documentation:

If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value. [...]

import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/accountController.getAccounts';

const COLUMNS = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'}
];

export default class AccountSearchCmp extends LightningElement {
    searchTerm;
    accList = [];
    
    get dataPresent() {
        return this.accList?.length;
    }

    get columns() {
        return COLUMNS;
    }

    @wire(getAccounts, {searchTerm: '$searchTerm'})
    wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else if(data){
            this.accList = data;
            console.log('Data: '+this.accList.length);
        }
    }

    handleSearch(event) {
        this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
        //console.log(this.searchTerm);
    }
}


Just a little thing. I've been bitten by using truthy values for booleans, but when we pass the value to a child/grandchild, its just a string/number.  i.e I've been using return this.accList?.length > 0; instead of return this.accList?.length;.  Maybe it's a sign my components aren't type checking/normalizing their inputs...

In your HTML template, you can only use variables defined inside the JavaScript class. The columns variable is currently defined outside the class, which makes it a static variable. Because of this, the datatable is receiving undefined instead of the column definitions.
Here's an updated version of your JavaScript code where the columns variable is defined inside the class:
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/accountController.getAccounts';

export default class AccountSearchCmp extends LightningElement {
    @track searchTerm = '';
    @track accList = [];
    @track dataPresent = false;
    columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone' }
    ];

    @wire(getAccounts, { searchTerm: '$searchTerm' })
    wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else if (data) {
            this.accList = data;
            this.dataPresent = data.length > 0;
            console.log('Data: ' + this.accList.length);
        } else {
            this.dataPresent = false;
        }
    }

    handleSearch(event) {
        this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
    }
}

Or You can assign the columns variable to a variable (columnsInsideJs)  inside the class:
In JS file:
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/accountController.getAccounts';

const columns = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'}
];

export default class AccountSearchCmp extends LightningElement {
    columnsInsideJs = columns;
    @track searchTerm;
    @track accList = [];
    @track dataPresent = false;
    @wire(getAccounts,{searchTerm: '$searchTerm'})
    wiredAccounts({error,data}){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else if(data){
            this.accList = data;
            console.log('Data: '+this.accList.length);
            if(this.accList.length>0){
                this.dataPresent = true; 
            }
        } else {
            this.dataPresent = false;
        }
    }

    handleSearch(event){
        this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
        //console.log(this.searchTerm);
    }
}

In HTML file:
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-input label="Search Accounts" name="search-accounts" onchange={handleSearch}></lightning-input>
        <template if:true={dataPresent}>
            <div style="height: 300px">
                <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={accList}
                columns={columnsInsideJs}
                hide-checkbox-column="true">
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:false={dataPresent}>
            <p>No Accounts found.</p>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

